# How to return two things inside a python 3 function?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to turn my Caesar Cypher code into an exe file, and I did. But the problem I'm having is that it immediately closes once it finishes, so I can't even see the encrypted text. I've thought of adding an input like "press 1 to repeat"  so I'm turning the whole asking for user input thing into its own function that can be looped, but it has to return the encrypted message and its key.

Is there a way of returning one string value and a list, inside one function?

Comment: Can you show us your current code? It's much more easy to help you then.

Comment: Return a tuple containing those things `return (message, key)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Python supports multiple return values for functions by separating the return values with commas. e.g.,

```
def foo():

    return 1, 2, 3

a, b, c = foo()
```

Where printing `a`, `b`, and `c` respectively gives the following:

```
>>> print(a)
1
>>> print(b)
2
>>> print(c)
3
```